# Rx Java observable not emitting the correct state executes once with initial value passed to fold

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

```
enum class CurrentState {
   SUCCESS,
   FAILURE
}

class ExecutorNode(
  private val execute: () -> Observable<CurrentState>
 ) : Node(emptyArray()) {
override fun getNodeState(): Observable<CurrentState> {
    return execute.invoke()
}
}

open class Node(
  private val children: Array<Node>
) {

open fun getNodeState(): Observable<CurrentState> {
    if (children.isEmpty()) {
        return Observable.just(CurrentState.FAILURE)
    }
    return children.fold(
        initial = Observable.just(CurrentState.FAILURE),
        operation = { observable: Observable<CurrentState>, node: Node ->
            observable.flatMap { nodeState ->
                if (nodeState == CurrentState.SUCCESS) {
                    Observable.just(nodeState)
                } else {
                    node.getNodeState()
                }
            }
        })
}
}
```

UNIT TESTS BEGIN HERE

```
class NodeTest {
private lateinit var node: Node
val testSubscriber = TestObserver<CurrentState>()

@Before
fun setup() {
    val executorNode = ExecutorNode { StateReporter(CurrentState.FAILURE).getNodeState() }

    val children = Array(2) { executorNode }
    node = Node(children as Array<Node>)
}

@Test
fun getNodeState_FAILURE() {
    node.getNodeState().subscribe(testSubscriber)
    testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1)
    testSubscriber.assertValues(CurrentState.FAILURE)
 }
}

class StateReporter(private val nodeState: CurrentState)  {
  fun getNodeState(): Observable<CurrentState> {
    return Observable.just(nodeState).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }
}
```

When I debug my code and test the `getNodeState_FAILURE` I do not receive any assertions while debugging my code I see only the initial `Failure` within `fold` gets executed the subsequent children node state do not return any failure. On a side not the property of the node is that it passes if any of the child nodes has SUCCESS it's like an OR operator. Could someone please guide me on why the observables are not getting subscribed. Do I have to subscribe again in the else clause (`node.getNodeState()`) for the child nodes to traverse the tree properly?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your intent from reading the code, but I suspect you want to create a single Observable instance using something like Observable.generate(...):
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#generate